# How to select all elements where child element satisfies given condition

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

As an example on that part of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Working with python and selenium I try to select all the books (let's assume that the list can be much larger) with price lower than 30.
I know that after finding the proper price I can select parent element with something like:

```
//book/price[..]
```

I found some ways to select elements with specific child or value/text of child, but I'm not sure how to check it with condition and I just can't glue it all together. I'll be grateful for any piece of advise. Of course it can be css selector, xpath selector, whatever suits better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
//bookstore/book[price<30]
```

Comment: Fast check on FirePath says it's invalid selector. And it selects price anyway, not whole book, but without that price at the end effect is the same :/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I used it as css, not xpath. It works. I knew it is something easy, but couldn't catch it. Thanks.